# Java Split a string on a backslash

Tags: java, string

I have a path to a file stored as a string: `"C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\foo.txt"`.  I want to isolate just the `"foo.txt"` part, so I try to split the string on a backslash, like so `"C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\foo.txt".split("\\")`, then get the last element of the array.  If I understand correctly, then the first backslash should escape the second, making it not a special character, so that the string would split on a backslash character.  However, when I run the code, I get a `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException` thrown.  What is the proper way to split on backslashes in java?

Comment: You should also be aware that your code will not work on any other machine without that file path.  The situation is impossible if this is a web app.  You should use classpath and file streams.

Comment: @duffymo I'm aware, that was just an example

Answer (score 8):

Oh no... please don't start messing with Windows filenames. One thing you don't want is to have platform-dependent code. Rather than this, use standard Java library:

```
System.out.println(new File("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\foo.txt").getName());
```

Finally, if you really had to parse the path manually, I would use `File.separatorChar` to make the code portable.

```
// hardcoded here for the example, but you would actually get it from somewhere
String path = "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\foo.txt"; 

int i = path.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar);
String last = i < 0 || i == s.length() ? "" : path.substring(i + 1);
System.out.println(last);
```

This is also less expensive than splitting a string since you're only interested in the last element.

Comment: This will not even compile. You should use forward slashes in Windows filenames actually, but if you use backslashes in string literals you have to escape them.

Comment: @EJP yep I know, just hastily copied the first string from the OP, but the principle is there. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The backslash is reserved, so you have to use a double-backslash like so:

```
filename.split("\\\\")
```

To make this solution work consistently across platforms, however, it would be better to use:

```
filename.split(Pattern.quote(File.separator))
```

Alternatively, as Dici pointed out, you could just do:

```
new File(filename).getName()
```

Comment: Although I know this is the right answer, I still find this surprising. In a Java regex, \\ denotes a backslah. It also denotes a backslah in a non-regex string, so why would it be different in a split ?

Comment: @Dici No. In a regex, `\\` is an escape character: if you mean a backslash you have to escape it. Then you have to escape them both again if you put them into a string literal. So you end up with four.

Comment: Ironically, it looks like Stack Overflow also escapes backslashes

Comment: @EJP https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html. \\ is the escape for a backslash, that's what I mean.

Comment: @Dici in Java regex, \\ denotes a backslash. But the string literal form of \\ is "\\\\", since backslash is an escape character in string literals as well as regex.

Comment: Yeah actually scratch that, \\ is never valid in a regex. That's a bit sad, it would be cool if Java had a syntax for writing regex outside of a string (like `/\\/`). I always find it lame not being able to copy paste a regex from Java to a regex tool or vice-versa